# React-router v4 updates url but doesn't render component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using react-router v4, no redux. The code example is below:

```
class MainPage extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="MainPage">
              <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                  {/* <Route exact path='/' /> */}
                  <Route path='/signin' component={SignIn}/>
                  <Route path='/signup' component={SignUp} />
                  <Redirect from='*' to='/' />
                </Switch>
              </BrowserRouter>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

When I'm using Link it updates URL in browser but doesn't render anything, nothing happens. When I resfresh, everything becomes fine and component renderes;

```
export default class Navbar extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="navbar">
              <BrowserRouter>
                <div>
                    <Link to='/signin'>Sign in</Link>
                    <Link to='/signup'>Sign up</Link>
                </div>
              </BrowserRouter>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I already tried everything, even withRouter(Component), but it says that with router may only be used inside 
How can I deal with this?

Comment: First, you should remove BrowserRouter in the NavBar, then move this Navbar component to your MainPage, and put it inside the div with the class name "MainPage" but above the BrowserRouter. Hope it works

Comment: Where do you render your Navbar

Comment: I changed the code in MainPage component and removed BrowserRouter from Navbar, and added Navbar in mainpage div above BrowserRouter, but now react tells me - You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working code. As others explained you should use one `BrowserRouter`. If you want to render your `Navbar` component all the time then you should place it above `Switch` but under `BrowserRouter` hence you need `Link` there.

```
const Navbar = () => (
      <div className="navbar">
            <Link to='/signin'>Sign in</Link>
            <Link to='/signup'>Sign up</Link>
      </div>
);

class MainPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="MainPage">
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
                <Navbar />
                <Switch>
                    {/* <Route exact path='/' /> */}
                    <Route path='/signin' component={SignIn} />
                    <Route path='/signup' component={SignUp} />
                    <Redirect from='*' to='/' />
               </Switch>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should only have a single `BrowserRouter` component in your tree.  The `BrowserRouter` component holds the shared state the router used to synchronize the URL with the rendered routes.  In your situation, you are getting two different versions of router state because you rendering two `BrowserRouter` components so you should probably render a single `BrowserRouter` component somewhere higher in your component tree.

If you have an `App` component that renders both `Navbar` and `MainPage` then you can move the router into that component:

```
export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
              <div className="AppContainer">
                <Navbar />
                <MainPage />
              </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed the code in MainPage component and removed BrowserRouter from Navbar, and added Navbar in mainpage div above BrowserRouter, but now react tells me - You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>

Comment: How are `Navbar` and `MainPage` rendered?  Do you have other components that are rendering `Navbar` and `MainPage`?

Comment: they rendrering in App component, <Navbar /> first, then <MainPage />